# How to inflate a view from a fragment?

Tags: android, wizard, android-inflate

I wanted to try out [WizarDroid](https://github.com/Nimrodda/WizarDroid/wiki/Simple-Wizard-Tutorial) library in my app. But since I am fairly inexperienced with inflators I got stuck on this error for hours.

I get a *NullPointerException* while trying to *findViewById* and I can't figure out why.

```
public class WizardStep1 extends WizardStep {

    //Wire the layout to the step
    public WizardStep1() {
    }

    //Set your layout here
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.wizard, container, false);
        TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.wizard_textView); // tv = null
        tv.setText("This is an example of Step 1 in the wizard. Press the Next " + // NullPointerException gets thrown here
                "button to proceed to the next step. Hit the back button to go back to the calling activity.");

        return v;
    }
}
```

So *TextView tv* is null for some reason. I can't figure this out because I clearly defined it in XML *R.layout.wizard*

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/wizard_textView"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:text="gtsets" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This code is also from their documentation so it just further confuses me :/

Edit:
Here's wizardStartup class :

```
public class wizardStartup extends BasicWizardLayout {

    /**
     * Note that initially BasicWizardLayout inherits from {@link android.support.v4.app.Fragment} and therefore you must have an empty constructor
     */
    public wizardStartup() {
        super();
    }

    //You must override this method and create a wizard flow by
    //using WizardFlow.Builder as shown in this example
    @Override
    public WizardFlow onSetup() {
        /* Optionally, you can set different labels for the control buttons
        setNextButtonLabel("Advance");
        setBackButtonLabel("Return");
        setFinishButtonLabel("Finalize"); */

        return new WizardFlow.Builder()
                .addStep(WizardStep1.class)           //Add your steps in the order you want them
                .addStep(WizardStep2.class)           //to appear and eventually call create()
                .create();                              //to create the wizard flow.
    }
}
```

LogCat :

> 07-15 17:58:05.491  10299-10299/ba.imasoft.dfms.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       java.lang.NullPointerException
>               at ba.imasoft.dfms.app.wizards.steps.WizardStep1.onCreateView(WizardStep1.java:28)

Line 28 is 'tv.setText("This'..

If I comment out the lines that contain tv variable It works but not the way It's supposed to.. I need to edit the view for each step.

tv = null proof...

[image: watches]

Comment: I don't see where you've defined your TextView in your XML?

Comment: If the layout you posted is R.layout.wizard Xml then I don't see the TextView with id R. id.wizard_textView. Please check your layout again.

Comment: Yeah, that's why is null, findViewById returns null if the ID is not found.

Comment: is the XML file name exactly wizard.xml?

Comment: Yes It is. wizard.xml

Comment: @l0oky This is puzzling. Is wizard.xml in res/layout, and there are no other wizard.xml files in other directories?

Comment: @matiash Correct. There is only one wizard.xml in res/layout.

Comment: @l0oky And in other directories? Such as layout-port, layout-large, ...? Because as stated, this error would seem "impossible" :)

Comment: @matiash haha you're starting to scare me because I don't have any other wizard.xml layouts or 'layout-large' packages..

Comment: How did you find tv is null? If LogCat, please show it.

Comment: I debugged.. Added tv to Watch and while the breakpoint was on line 'tv.setText("..' It said that tv = null.

Comment: Isn't it annoying when you get downvotes but not answers? :)

Comment: @david.pfx I edited the question with logcat. And that's the only thing 'useful' I got from it.

Comment: From this and your answer I would say that the true cause is something you aren't telling us. VTC.

Comment: @david.pfx So I was supposed to tell you the answer while I didn't know it? I was perfectly clear about every class, name and library. Not to mention the other details. It clearly says in my answer 'I can't figure this out because I clearly defined it in XML R.layout.wizard' so the problem was in the name that XML the library required..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was bizarrely strange..

Anyway all I did is change **wizard.xml** to **wizard_step.xml** figured it was using **wizard.xml** as something else in the library hmm..

It worked.

Comment: That is very much correct! The library already has a layout file named `wizard.xml` as you can see [here](https://github.com/Nimrodda/WizarDroid/blob/develop/wizardroid/src/main/res/layout/wizard.xml). I will add it to the FAQ and rename this file in future releases.